# Unable to access a ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I have a MainActivity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
} }
```

and this

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    int count = getListView().getCount();
    getListView().setSelection(getListView().getCount() - 1);


    test();

}

public void test(){
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    int count = getListView().getCount();
    getListView().setSelection(getListView().getCount() - 1);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ccc"+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

} }
```

The activity_main.xml has a

```
fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.mike.mqtt.MyListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content" />
```

When the application starts I get the fragment_content filled up with some rows.
How can I access the ListFragment(MyListFragment.java) from inside the MainActivity.java in the onCreate.
When I press a button the get the ListFragment content count, and to set focus at the end of the list.

I have no idea.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyListFragment fragment = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using fragments in XML as it alows me to replace them on-the-fly. I usually use something like this:

```
private MyListFragment mListFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // the usual business

  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // the activity opened for the first time, we create and commit fragment
    mListFragment = new MyListFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, f).commit);
  } else {
    // activity is recreating so it's safe to find already added fragments
    mListFragment = fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
  }
```

}